# Load movie into iPhone in landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C coding, so I beg your pardon for the stupid question. I must do something very simple: I load a local video and, when it stops playing, it starts again from the beginning.

So, first of all, **I would like to know if the code I used is correct** (that is: if it can generate memory leaks or there are for example things that, given my basic experience, I should consider and I did not).

Another thing is **what can I do to have my video covering the entire screen in landscape mode**. If I choose `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` (or `Right`) in the Simulator I see my video in a rectangle in the bottom-left corner (then I get two areas, a grey one and a black one).

I removed the comments because they're not in English.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self startPlayingVideo];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void) startPlayingVideo{
    //
    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *urlAsString = [mainBundle pathForResource:@"space" ofType:@"mp4"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlAsString];
    //
    MPMoviePlayerController *newMoviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    //
    self.moviePlayer = newMoviePlayer; 
    //
    [newMoviePlayer release]; 
    //
    [self.view addSubview:self.moviePlayer.view];
    //
    [self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoHasFinishedPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
    //
    self.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
    //
    // play
    [self.moviePlayer play];
    //
    // fullscreen
    [self.moviePlayer setFullscreen:YES animated:YES];
}

-(void)videoHasFinishedPlaying:(NSNotification*)paramNotification{
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(videoHasFinishedPlaying:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.moviePlayer];
    self.moviePlayer.initialPlaybackTime = -1.0;
    [self.moviePlayer play];
    //
}
```

Thank you very much for any suggestion.

**[EDIT]** I found I can hardcode this line `[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: self.view.bounds]` and change it to `[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 640,360)]` to match either the movie dimensions and the iPhone screen dimensions.

It looks like `self.view.bounds` doesn't return 640x360, but 460x320: these are the XIB dimensions (and it seems they can't be changed through the XCode Inspector). Same issue with `UIScreen`. By adding `return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);` to the `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation:interfaceOrientation:` method, I get anything working as expected but **it remains the problem of the hardcoded dimensions**.

In the meantime I easily got rid of the `NSNotificationCenter` (I discovered the property `repeatMode` of the `MPMoviePlayerController` class).

**[EDIT 2]** Finally, anything seems to work fine by inverting W and H this way:   `[self.moviePlayer.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width)]` and adding `newMoviePlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill`. I don't know if this is the best way to proceed, but...